# Angular google map main controller error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to get angular-google-maps on my site with 'markers'.

Here is the code I am using : 
 controller main.js

```
angular.module('dashyAppApp')
    .factory("Markers", function(){
      var Markers = [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "coords": {
            "latitude": "45.5200",
            "longitude": "-122.6819"
          },
          "window": {
            "title": "Portland, OR"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "coords": {
            "latitude": "40.7903",
            "longitude": "-73.9597"
          },
          "window" : {
            "title": "Manhattan New York, NY"
          }
        }
      ];
      return Markers;
    });

    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,Markers) {
      $scope.map = { 
        center: { latitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795 }, 
        zoom: 4 
      };
      $scope.markers = Markers;
    });
```

And here is my view main.html

```
<ui-gmap-google-map 
          center='map.center' 
          zoom='map.zoom' aria-label="Google map">

          <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers"
            coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
            <ui-gmap-window>
              <div>{{marker.window.title}}</div>
            </ui-gmap-window>
          </ui-gmap-marker>

        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I keep getting this errors:

```
markerwithlabel.js:71 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(anonymous function) @ markerwithlabel.js:71
infobox.js:116 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(anonymous function) @ infobox.js:116
keydragzoom.js:820 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(anonymous function) @ keydragzoom.js:820(anonymous function) @ keydragzoom.js:861
richmarker.js:60 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(anonymous function) @ richmarker.js:60
main.js:37 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1885:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1895:3)
    at $controller (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10210:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4095:28)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1240:18
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9814:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9215:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8510:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8390:30)
```

I don't know why it won't work and for one the 'google is not defined error' is just out of place because the map shows well when I show just one marker without the .factory.

Comment: Could you set a jsfiddle link so that i can help to debug?

Comment: you didn't use $scope in your controller method. Use like this
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
//
});

Comment: @DurgpalSingh there is scope .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,Markers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Markers;
    });

    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,Markers) {
      $scope.map = {
```

take out the  semicolon before `.controller` first. this is causing your controller not configured.

Comment: Thanks for the sharp eyes. That was the problem.  Except the google is not defined output `markerwithlabel.js:71 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
infobox.js:116 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
keydragzoom.js:820 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
richmarker.js:60 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Comment: have u imported these libraries? like `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>`?

Comment: I have this added when I installed it using bower  `<script src="bower_components/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/google-maps-utility-library-v3-markerwithlabel/dist/markerwithlabel.js"></script>`

Comment: it actually says that _google is not defined_ which means that either u didn't add the google api itself or you put it after the utilities.